# Count of person more and equal to 3

Tags: sql

Good day

here is the task i have been given:
*Please could you let me have a report of the Thebemed and Hosmed patients that have been admitted more than 3 x over the past 6 months*

And here is the coding i have :
*

How can i narrow the members down to => 3

Comment: "more than 3" means >3 to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE..
GROUP BY...
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: I only have one more problem ,I only want Membername that hade more than 3 entry's not the entire range

Comment: can you give sample records with the desired result?

Comment: Is there a way i can attach a excel file so that i could give you sample data

Comment: actually you can simplify it `:D` just add the data in tabular form along with your question. just simplify.